# Unable to serve html file using 'http' module of Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, response

I am trying to serve an html page as a response to '/' request on my http server.
But somehow it's not working.

My index.html is -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Explorer</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<script>
    var fileExplorerApp = angular.module('explorerApp', []);
    fileExplorerApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
        var currentPath = '';
        $scope.reload = function (newPath, back) {
            if (back) {
                currentPath = newPath;
            } else {
                if (currentPath === '') {
                    currentPath = newPath;
                } else {
                    currentPath = currentPath + '/' + newPath;
                }
            }
            console.log('Newpath- ' + currentPath);
            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/list_dir?path=' + currentPath)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.filesAndFolders = response.data;
                    $scope.currentPath = currentPath;
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('Error in $http- ' + error);
                });    
        }

        $scope.back = function () {
            var prevPath = currentPath.substring(0, currentPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
            console.log('Path after substring- ' + prevPath);
            console.log('Prevpath when back clicked- ' + prevPath);
            $scope.reload(prevPath, true);

        }

        $scope.reload('F:/', false);
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="explorerApp" ng-controller="MyController">

<div class="ui container">
    <h1 id="currentPath">Current Directory- {{ currentPath }}</h1>
    <button ng-if="currentPath !== 'F:/'"
            ng-click="back()"
            class="ui left labeled icon button">
        <i class="left arrow icon"></i>
        Back
    </button>
    <div class="ui list">
        <a class="item"
           ng-repeat="item in filesAndFolders"
           ng-click="reload(item.name, false)"
           ng-href="{{item.type === 'file' ? '/get_file?path='+currentPath+'/'+item.name : ''}}">
            <i ng-if="item.type === 'folder'" class="folder icon"></i>
            <i ng-if="item.type === 'file'" class="file icon"></i>
            {{ item.name }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Via angular i'm accessing another route '/list_dir' and handling the request using 'http' module of Node.js(Not Express).

```
if(parsedUrl.pathname === '/list_dir') {
            console.log('I\'m here');
            var file_path = parsedUrl.query['path'];
            list_dir.listDir(file_path, function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    res.writeHeader(400, {'Content-Type':'text/json'});
                    res.write(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('in list_dir, no errors- response is- '+data);
                    res.writeHeader(200,{'Contenttype':'application/json'});
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });
            res.end();
            break;
        }
```

The route '/list_dir' then accesses a function in another script which is this-

```
module.exports = {
listDir: function (path, myCallback) {
    var resultObj = [];

    fs.readdir(path, function (err, data) {
        console.log('In listDir');
        if (err) {
            switch(err.code){
                case 'EACCES':
                    return myCallback({errno: err.errno, description: 'An attempt was made to access a file in a way forbidden by its file access permissions.'}, null);
                case 'ENOENT':
                    return myCallback({errno: err.errno, description: 'The specified path does not exist.'});
                case 'EPERM':
                    return myCallback({errno: err.errno, description: 'An attempt was made to perform an operation that requires elevated privileges.'})
                case 'ENOTDIR':
                    return myCallback({errno: err.errno, description: 'The specified path is not a directory.'})
            }
            return myCallback(err, null);
        }

        var itemsCompleted = 0;
        data.forEach(function (value) {
            fs.lstat(path + '/' + value, function (err, stats) {
                itemsCompleted++;
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    if (stats.isFile()) {
                        resultObj.push({
                            type: 'file',
                            name: value,
                            size: stats['size']
                        });
                        //resultObj.push(value);
                        //console.log(resultObj + '\n');
                    } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                        resultObj.push({
                            type: 'folder',
                            name: value,
                            size: stats['size']
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (itemsCompleted >= data.length) {
                    //console.log(resultObj);
                    return myCallback(null, resultObj)
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

};

This function return a json object of all the files/folders inside the given path, which will be provided to the '/list_dir' route. But i'm not getting the correct response from the route.

I want this route to respond with the same json that is returned by the listDir function. I'm new to the http module of Node.js, maybe ive written the header wrong or i'm consuming the data in a wrong way. Please help. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Chirags answer was correct and now '/list_dir' route is returning the correct json response. However, i'm still not able to serve the index.html file where i'm using AngularJS to consume this route.

This is how i'm handling the route-

```
if (parsedUrl.pathname === '/') {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function (err, fileResponse) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error');
            res.writeHeader(404, {
                "Content-Type": "text/html"
            });
            res.write('There was an error!');
        } else {
            console.log('No error');
            res.writeHeader(200, {
                "Content-Type": "text/html"
            });
            res.write(fileResponse);
        }
        res.end();
    });
}
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: The code you have posted looks okay at first glance. can you post your entire file where you set up the server and call `listen` etc? PS: If your question is not fully answered, don't mark an answer as accepted. (Bye reputation ;( ).. Other people will not look at this

Comment: Does `console.log('No error');` print in your callback?  My best guess is that your path matching may not be working as expected and that block of code never gets executed

Comment: Yes it does. 
This is what it prints exactly- 

`Server has been started at port 3000
The url is - / 
The pathname is - / `
No error` 

It does not go to the '/list_dir' route to fetch initial result form listDir function. I somehow think the angular code isn't working.

Comment: It does print 'No error'

Comment: `I somehow think the angular code isn't working` When you visit `/` in your browser, do you see the html come up? The problem can be with angular if your web page loads but your JS on it doesn't run. What do you see in your browser when you visit `/`?

Comment: I see nothing. It keeps on waiting for the response. I don't even see the html.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your response stream too early. Basically, `res.end()` gets executed before your asynchronous function to read the directory gets executed and the callback is invoked. Try:

```
if (parsedUrl.pathname === '/list_dir') {
    console.log('I\'m here');
    var file_path = parsedUrl.query['path'];
    list_dir.listDir(file_path, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHeader(400, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/json'
            });
            res.write(err);
        } else {
            console.log('in list_dir, no errors- response is- ' + data);
            res.writeHeader(200, {
                'Contenttype': 'application/json'
            });
            res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        res.end();
    });
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant code? It's usually a simple case of using `fs.readFile` and writing the file to the response in the callback using `res.write`. If you want to stream the response, you can even get a readstream and pipe that to your response object using `res.pipe(fileStream)`

Comment: Not sure what your usecase is but using [Express](https://expressjs.com/) or something similar makes common tasks like routing and sending files easy by abstracting away some of the more obscure NodeJS concepts

Comment: That's absolutely true and that's how i did it initially. 
This was actually an assignment given to me. I did it through Express but they wanted it to be done by the 'http' module alone and not use a framework. Therein lies the problem.

Comment: To give you a little insight of my use case, this is a simple assignment where i must make a web app to browse the files on my computer.
Refer to- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272330/function-behaving-asynchronously-even-after-a-callback-function-in-node-js)